# Phase change during polarisation

Tags: polarization

A beam of coherent unpolarised light is split into two. One is polarised horizontally, the other vertically. Will there be a phase difference between the two beams?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense for unpolarized light to be coherent.

Comment: Light from a monochromatic source that first passes through one slit would be coherent but unpolarised before it arrives at a two-slit screen, wouldn't it?

Comment: The light illuminating the two slits may be spatially coherent in that case, meaning the light reaching the slits would have the same phase. However temporal coherence depends on the light source. If it is perfectly monochromatic, it would also be temporally coherent. But if it is perfectly temporally coherent, I don't think it can be unpolarized. The source could still have a long coherence time and be partially polarized though.